# Power function applied to complex number

Tags: functions, complex

In part of the full form of the Mathematica output, I observe this expression: 
Power[Complex[1, 1], Rational[2, 3]]

But I am not sure how to interpret this: technically, the power function is not a function, since its first argument is complex and its second argument is *not*  integer. Then, how should I interpret the above output? I found the following article:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexExponentiation.html
Is this the way mathematica treats the power function?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quoting from the Documentation Center page for `Power`, under "Possible Issue": "Power always computes principal roots". This is also alluded to in the "Details" section: "Because of this branch cut, Power[x,1/n] returns a complex root by default instead of the real one for negative real x and odd positive n."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **function** [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power.html) is defined for complex arguments

```
expr = Power[Complex[1, 1], Rational[2, 3]]

(*  (1 + I)^(2/3)  *)

expr // N

(*  1.09112 + 0.629961 I  *)
```

From the documentation for `Power`, "x^y gives x to the power y. ...For complex numbers x and y, Power gives the principal value of e^(y log (x))."

```
(1 + I)^(2/3) == Exp[2/3 Log[1 + I]] // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

**EDIT:** See documentation on [`Functions That Do Not Have Unique Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatDoNotHaveUniqueValues.html)

Comment: Thank you. Your response together with the comments of Daniel and JM answers my problem! This was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a complex power raised to a (complex) number is most of the time a complicated term. Mathematica just tries to save you from this mess and does not give a full representation but rather stays unevaluated. But you can simply force it to evaluate the Power with [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html).

So as you wrote it like this:

```
ComplexExpand[Power[Complex[1, 1], Rational[2, 3]]]
```

or as i would write it:

```
(1 + I)^(2/3) // ComplexExpand
```

both give the same answer:

> I/2^(2/3) + Sqrt[3]/2^(2/3)

Which is nice and simple in the normal $a+i\, b$ form

Comment: Thanks a lot. Because I has n n-th roots, then ComplexExpand[I^(1/n)] (mathematically) must return n values. But it seems that mathematica picks exactly one of them. My question is, how does mathematica decide to pick which one?

Comment: @afshi7n, look up "principal value".

Comment: @Daniel, J.M. Thanks a lot, it was very helpful. I could not find a definition for principal roots in Mathematica documentation center, but I found this online: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_root_of_unity. Do you think Mathematica uses the same definition?  
Also, a quick separate question: with this definition of Power, I think (a*b)^c=(a^c) * (b^c) would not hold generally, for example when 0<c<1. Is this correct? Thanks a lot for all your help!

Comment: @afshi7n, it uses the definition consistent with the value of $\arg$ being in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: (1) Use [this ref](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/nthRoot.html) and [see also](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatDoNotHaveUniqueValues.html). (2) You are correct that that will not hold in general (that fact is independent of what choice of root is used).