# Complex Solutions not in a+bi form

Tags: complex

```
 Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x]
```

gives the solution:

```
{{x -> -(-1)^(1/3)}, {x -> (-1)^(2/3)}}
```

I know these are complex solutions but I'd like to have them in a+bi form. If I do `N@Solve`...I get the right form but as you can imagine I get numeric approximations.

Any ideas on how to have the solutions be in a+bi form but with exact expressions? I'm pretty sure there's a way to do it by messing with Re[] and Im[] but I'd rather not. Is there a quick way to do this? I am actually surprised the a+bi form isn't the default way to show complex solutions.

Comment: This really belongs in the docs. They point out the problem, but they do not solve it with `ComplexExpand` (but with `N`, which is not equivalent at all). It should also be mentioned in "Background & Context." They use `ComplexExpand` only once, on a rather esoteric problem.

Comment: Related, but closed: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141949/power-function-applied-to-complex-number

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x] // ComplexExpand

(* {{x -> -(1/2) - (I Sqrt[3])/2}, {x -> -(1/2) + (I Sqrt[3])/2}} *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: could use `//ExpToTrig`as well

Comment: @ Andreas In Mma there are often several ways to get the same solution. However, I believe that in the answers here, at StackExchange, it is valuable to demonstrate all of them, even if the question has already been answered. Why don't you write your approach as a regular answer? Somebody will like it more.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness: A second way to achieve the desired form is

```
Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x] // ExpToTrig
```

Answer (score 1):

For fun.

```
Solve[x^2 + x + 1 == 0, x] /. x_?NumericQ :> Re@x + I Im@x
```